# Flask - How to get session value that was set from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Given the script below, I tried to get javascript session value in Flask via Python script as below:

**JS Script**

In javascript, I set session with `DataMulti` the value as below:

```
DataJson = [{Gender:'boy', FirstName:'Jonh', LastName:'Smith'},{Gender:'girl', FirstName:'Mary', LastName:'Smith'}]
    
sessionStorage.setItem('DataMulti', JSON.stringify(DataJson))
```

**Python Script**

Then in python script, I try to access that session key value via flask as this:

```
from flask import request, session

print('My session: ',session.get('DataMulti')) # null
```

However, the value I got is `null`. If I set another session inside python script directly, the session is working as fine:

```
session['firstName'] = "Jquery"

print(session.get('firstName')) # Jquery
```

Why it is like that? How can I get session value that is set from Javascript? Thanks

Comment: `sessionStorage` is a browser local storage. It is not cookie storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session storage in js stores the data in Webbrowser so that you can retrieve it somewhere else in the js code. It has nothing to do with the data passed to the server in an HTTP session. Similarly, the session in the flask is for storing data to retrieve elsewhere in flask code. These are separated by a process boundary and are not linked to each other.

To send the data, you will have to do a post request and store the data in flask using the session.

```
# Handle post request in flask
session['data'] = request.json
```

To use this data elsewhere,

```
data = session.get('data', None)
```

Comment: Thanks every much, is there any method beside sending data with Ajax. Because data I'm going from front-end is json object that can be too long to attach with URL, in method GET. Also that data is encoded, something like this `http://localhost:5000/getCustomerInfo?POCustomer=POCustomer&DataMulti=%5B%7B%22Gender%22%3A%22boy%22%2C%22FirstName%22%3A%22Jonh%22%2C%22LastName%22%3A%22Smith%22%7D%2C%7B%22Gender%22%3A%22girl%22%2C%22FirstName%22%3A%22Mary%22%2C%22LastName%22%3A%22Smith%22%7D%5D` which is hard to decode it back in backend. Thanks

Comment: I'm not using method POST because i'm not going to store data, but to process it and send it back to display in front-end only, that's a reason I use session store instead, but sadly it is not like i think :(. Thanks.

Comment: You can send data with a get request too. But I feel a post is the right thing here. I know you are not storing it but sometimes you have to be pragmatic. Flask can deal with JSON data very well. Check it out. But since the data is big, it's better if its in the request body rather than in the url.

Comment: I got it with method GET, flask already handle decoding string url for me, I just concern when the URL is too long that would exceed limit.

Comment: Exactly. So don't send it in the URL. Send it in the request body instead.

Comment: I could not use POST method since my developer develop all their logic in GET method only.